# Empty column header in table using github markdown?

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

Currently trying to format a table using github markdown. Would like to have something like:

```
       | col1 | col2
    -- | ---- | ----
    r1 |  r2  |  r3
```

However markdown is forcing me to place text in the first column for the table to render. Any thoughts on how I could maintain an empty first column header?

Comment: You could just use `&nbsp;`. That would add a non-breaking space (which is not strictly empty, but is at least invisible). Or you can start your heading row with a `|` (not sure it's *supposed* to work, but it does).

Comment: sorry not sure why i didn't respond to this earlier, but this works!! much thanks. feel free to provide as answer and i can accept

Answer (score 20):

So as this question can be marked as solved, I'll put [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) comment below:

> You could just use `&nbsp;`. That would add a non-breaking space (which is not strictly empty, but is at least invisible). Or you can start your heading row with a `|` (not sure it's supposed to work, but it does).